# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'xxx' has no index signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I encounter two case about this problem when I try to refactor a es6 project in typescript, and one is about `Object.keys()` and the other is about `import * as xxx`.

Case 1:

```
const SUPPORTED_VALUES = {
    min_s: 'Mininum similarity',
    max_rc: 'Maximum result count'
}
const UNSUPPORTED_MSG =
    'Configurable values:\n' +
    Object.keys(SUPPORTED_VALUES)
        .map(k => `${k}: ${SUPPORTED_VALUES[k]}`)
        .join('\n')
```

The `k` in the `map` is guaranteed to be a key in `SUPPORTED_VALUES`, but typescript compiler doesn't know about this. How should I fix this without disabling `noImplicitAny`?

Case 2:

I have a file called `cmd.ts`:

```
export async function cmd1(args){}
export async function cmd2(args){}
```

It is used is another file like this:

```
import * as cmdHandlers from './cmd'
// some code...
if (cmd in cmdHandlers) {
    await cmdHandlers[cmd](bot, msg, ...args)
}
```

This is also guaranteed that `cmd` exists in `cmdHandlers`, but typescript compiler can't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, you need define exactly type for `SUPPORTED_VALUES` like `{[key: string]: string}`

```
const SUPPORTED_VALUES: {[key: string]: string} = {
  min_s: 'Minimum similarity',
  max_rc: 'Maximum result count'
}
const UNSUPPORTED_MSG =
  'Configurable values:\n' +
  Object.keys(SUPPORTED_VALUES)
    .map(k => `${k}: ${SUPPORTED_VALUES[k]}`)
    .join('\n')
```

Case 2, The same case 1, `cmd` can be anything, but `cmdHandlers` only includes `cmd1` and `cmd2`. You can define your type for `cmd.ts` module to make `cmdHandlers` is a object with any property name.

I think it is ok, because you have a condition before call a function

// cmd.ts

```
async function cmd1(...args: any) { }
async function cmd2(...args: any) { }

const myExport: { [key: string]: (...args: any) => void } = {
  cmd1,
  cmd2,
}

export default myExport;
```

//

```
import cmdHandlers from './cmd'
// some code...
if (cmd in cmdHandlers) {
    await cmdHandlers[cmd](bot, msg, ...args)
}
```

Comment: For case 1, this requires widening the type signature of `SUPPORTED_VALUES`, though. Is there a way to keep it as `{
    min_s: string;
    max_rc: string;
}` without casting?

Comment: The `k` in case 1 and `cmd` in case 2 can't be anything, since the first is from `Object.keys()` and the second is checked by `if(cmd in cmdHandlers)`. I think it may be typescript compiler's limitation?